# How to cancel a common term from numerator(in the squarroot but squared) and denominator?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

following is the code. It can be seen that the result can be simplified by eliminating a gamma, but Mathematica does not eliminate this one. How to do it?

[image]

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"];
v = (m1 u1 + m2 u2)/(m1 + m2);

e1 = \[Gamma] Sqrt[( m1  m2/( m1 + m2) (u1 - u2))^2 + ( 
    m1)^2];
e2 = \[Gamma] Sqrt[( m1  m2/( m1 + m2) (u1 - u2))^2 + ( 
    m2)^2];
p3 = Sqrt[e3^2 - (\[Gamma] m3)^2] /. 
  Solve[{(\[Gamma] m1)^2 + (\[Gamma] m3)^2 - 
      2 e1 e3 == (\[Gamma] m2)^2 + (\[Gamma] m4)^2 - 2 e2 e4, 
    e1 + e2 == e3 + e4}, {e3, e4}];
p4 = -Sqrt[e4^2 - (\[Gamma] m4)^2] /. 
  Solve[{(\[Gamma] m1)^2 + (\[Gamma] m3)^2 - 
      2 e1 e3 == (\[Gamma] m2)^2 + (\[Gamma] m4)^2 - 2 e2 e4, 
    e1 + e2 == e3 + e4}, {e3, e4}];
p3 + p4 // Simplify;
u3 = p3/(\[Gamma] m3) - v // Simplify
u4 = -u3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell Mathematica something about the variables you are using, for example, that one of them is strictly positive. Otherwise, Mathematica will not know what to do with some expressions (just think what about if the variable would be imaginary?). An elementary example is

```
Sqrt[a^2]
```

> $\sqrt{a^2}$

For your case you can make global assumptions with `$Assumptions` which are used with `Simplify`

```
$Assumptions = {\[Gamma] > 0}
u3 = p3/(\[Gamma] m3) - v
u3 = p3/(\[Gamma] m3) - v // Simplify
```

[image]